# Which is correct: "The teacher spoke to my father and I" or "The teacher spoke to my father and me"?

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronouns

Which is correct: "The teacher spoke to my father and I" or "The teacher spoke to my father and me"?

I don't have any solid reason but I feel "The teacher spoke to my father and me." is the correct one out of the two.

But some claim that the latter is the correct version, i.e. "The teacher spoke to my father and I". Could someone please give reasons as to which one is correct and why? Thank you!

Comment: You might do some research into pronoun use in prepositional phrases.

Comment: Who claims "to my father and I" is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from

> The teacher spoke to my father and me.

If you break it into three variants

> The teacher spoke to my father.
>
> The teacher spoke to me.
>
> The teacher spoke to I.

The last one is wrong, so this should show your sentence is correct.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the reasoning isn't. Compare "It is my dog". "It is John's dog". "It is my and John's dog"?

Comment: @JamesK in your example it is **our** dog, so you suggest this answer should be **The teacher spoke to us** ?

Comment: I don't. The correct answer is the teacher spoke to my father and me. The answer is correct, but the reasoning isn't.